# Trigger Rollup Assets to Account

Tags: trigger

I am trying to rollup the values of the assets on a particular account to that Account's active products field. I receive an error when try updating an asset that the string is too long (my code seems to be grabbing multiple account's asset values and not the single account that I'm looking to update). Any help in updating the single account would be appreciated.

```
trigger BulkifyAssets on Asset (before insert, before update) {

Set<Account> listAccounts = new Set<Account>([Select Id, Name, BillingState, BillingCity, ProductsOwned__c from Account]);
        Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, ProductsOwned__c, Name, (Select Id, AccountId, Name, ProductFamily__c from Assets Where AccountId != null) 
                                                      From Account]);

    Map<Id,Asset> assetMap = new Map<Id,Asset>([Select Id, AccountId, Status, ProductFamily__c from Asset where Status !=null OR Status != 'Retired' OR Status != 'Obsolete' ]);

           Map<String,Account> accProductsOwnedMap = new Map<String,Account>();
    List<Account> setToList = new List<Account>();
    List<Asset> listAsset = new List<Asset>();

for(Asset a: trigger.new){

    for(Account account: [Select id, ProductsOwned__c from Account where Id =: a.AccountId]){
       listAccounts.add(account);
listAsset.add(a); 

    if(a.Status != null || a.status != 'Retired' || a.status != 'Obsolete' ){
     a.AccountId = account.Id;
        assetMap.put(a.Id,a);
        if(account.ProductsOwned__c != null){
    account.ProductsOwned__c += ',' + assetMap.values();
        }
        else{
     account.ProductsOwned__c += assetMap.values();            
        }
     accProductsOwnedMap.put(account.ProductsOwned__c, account);
        setToList.add(accMap.get(account.id));
            accMap.putall(setToList);
            } 
        }   
    }
    if(accProductsOwnedMap.size()>0)
    {
      update accProductsOwnedMap.values();
}

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you consider using [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) in Concatenate mode. It'll save you writing any code at all.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you know if this tool accounts for bulkification?

Comment: Yes, DLRS operates in a bulkified manner.